# error: incompatible types in assignment of 'int' to 'char [1]' in GEANY

Tags: c++

I have a very easy program, but when i try to compile this program it appears the error.
This is the Code:

```
int main(){
char Yes[1];
char No[1];
char c[1];
cout<<"Turtle or Fish"<< endl;
cout<<"Does it have legs?"<< endl;
cin>>c;
No=1;
Yes=2;
if (c==Yes){
    cout<<"Turtle"<<endl;
}if (c==No){
    cout<<"Fish"<<endl;
}
```

}

The error apears in Yes=2 and in No=1.
I have put only the iostream include.
How can I solve It??

Comment: You're declaring char arrays of size 1, and not chars. Remove the "[1]" after Yes, No and c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a mismatch of types and it's highly likely your code is not doing what you think it is. When you do:

```
char Yes[1];
```

you are creating `Yes` which is an array of `char`'s of length 1. Chances are if you are only ever going to be looking at one character then you should just define a `char` and not an array. Later on you then try to assign an integer to `Yes`. I suspect what you were trying to do was `Yes = '1'` here.